# Exception: Unable to find py4j in /content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

While setting up PySpark to run in Google Colab, I got this error:

`Exception: Unable to find py4j in /content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly`.

Above the code I used:

```
# Install java
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null

# Last version of Spar
!wget -q https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.2.1/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz

# Unzip spark
!tar xf /content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2

# Setting environment variable
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"

# Install findspark lib that help find spark in the system and import it as a regular lib
!pip install -q findspark
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7"

# Import findspark lib 
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

I changed spark version, but I got the exact some error. I don't understand why can't configure `SPARK_HOME` correctly if the instruction is correct.

Comment: why don't you just `pip install pyspark`?

Comment: You could try `findspark.init("/content/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7")`, see https://github.com/minrk/findspark

Comment: Also didn't work, but thanks.

Comment: I got this. Actually, the problem is due to the download link I was using. As reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240940/error-while-installing-spark-on-google-colab. The same issue and the answer solved my case too. Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a reference:

```
sys.path.append("/opt/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python")
sys.path.append("/opt/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked my tutor about this and we compared some other codes found on StackOverflow, and he said their website has changed to archive.apache.org, so try this line instead in your second line of code. Hopefully, it will work for you as it did for me and you should be able to source the data successfully.

`# Last version of Spar`

`!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.2.1/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz`